# How to get particular row values in dynamic table if the 'text ' matches in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

I can able to print all the values in webtable but not sure how to get particular row value.

Here I need print respective row value where text matches 'Aiden' because Aiden text might display in any of the row number there is no fixed position.

```
 driver.get("https://demoqa.com/elements");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              
//clicking the left menu

              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Web Tables']")).click(); 
                      
              //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rt-table']")).click();
              Thread.sleep(5000);

// selecting the table      
      
              WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rt-table']"));  

//selecting the table header    
      
                List<WebElement> tableheaders = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rt-thead -header']"));  

//printing all the table header values
                
                for (WebElement headername : tableheaders) {   
                    String text = headername.getText();
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

//selecting all row values
                        
                List<WebElement> allrows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='row' and @class='rt-tr -odd' or @class='rt-tr -even']")); 

// total row count

                int size = allrows.size();
                System.out.println("Rows size: "+size); 

// selecting all column values      
        
                for (int colnum = 0; colnum < size; colnum++) {
                    List<WebElement> colums = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rt-td' and @role='gridcell'] /..")); 
                    WebElement firstColumn = colums.get(colnum);
                    System.out.println(firstColumn.getText());
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty string variable and assign its value when the row contains the given keyword

```
        String rowValue = "";
        for (WebElement webElement : tableRows) {
            if (webElement.getText().contains(searchedValue)) {
                rowValue = webElement.getText();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rowValue);
```